# Nested Servlet exception while accessing Relational Data using JDBC with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm following this document-

http://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/#scratch

After setting the datasource, and creating a jdbcTemplate -

```
SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class);
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql:/uel.to.connect.the.db");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

When I am trying to make a select query -

```
List<GameBean> results = jdbcTemplate.query("select * from Games",
                new RowMapper<GameBean>() {
                    @Override
                    public GameBean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        GameBean gb = new GameBean();
                        gb.setGameId(rs.getInt("GameId"));
                        gb.setGameName(rs.getString("GameName"));
                        return gb;
                    }
                });
```

I'm getting  an error mentioning **"Could not get JDBC Connection;"**

```
   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'social_devuser'@'10.55.200.1' (using password: YES)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:382)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:464)
    com.service.games.dao.GamesDao.getAllGames(GamesDao.java:26)
    com.service.games.SpringServiceController.getGreeting(SpringServiceController.java:24)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be missing here?

Comment: Is your datasource url correct?

Comment: the datasource is getting created... the url is correct.

Comment: I dont see the reference of it in your logs.

Comment: I tried with different environment and now getting cannot connect to JDBC exception, although I am able to connect to the database using sql editor. Are there any settings which i might be overlooking here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure properly the access to your MySql schema:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'social_devuser'@'10.55.200.1' (using password: YES)
```

Maybe you have specified a wrong username/password in your config or you have no granted access to that user from 10.55.200.1 ip address

Comment: That is the first thing i did, I verified the creds and made sure i am able to access the db with the mentioned user.

Comment: mmm. the error is pretty clear :) have you tried to access your schema from 10.55.200.1? In case mysql and your container are on the same host try to grant access to localhost, or try with a % to be less restrictive.

Comment: Maybe you have not flushed privileges in mysql shell.. try FLUSH PRIVILEGES